# PostgreSQL INSERT into an array of enums

Tags: postgresql, types, enums, sql-insert

How can I insert an `array of enums`?
Here is my `enum`:

```
CREATE TYPE equipment AS ENUM ('projector','PAsystem','safe','PC','phone');
```

Then my table has an array of equipment:

```
CREATE TABLE lecture_room (
   id INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('lecture_id_seq')
 , seatCount int
 , equipment equipment[]
) INHERITS(venue);
```

Here is my ATTEMPT to INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO lecture_room (building_code, floorNo,  roomNo, length, width
                        , seatCount, equipment) 
VALUES 
('IT', 4, 2, 10, 15 ,120, ARRAY['projector','PAsystem','safe']),
```

But it gives me the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: column "equipment" is of type equipment[] but expression is of type text[]
> SQL state: 42804
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
> ```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't know how to automatically cast input of type `text` to input of type `equipment`. You have to explicitly declare your strings as being of type `equipment`:

```
ARRAY['projector','PAsystem','safe']::equipment[]
```

I confirmed this with [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/84981/8).

Answer (score 24):

The alternative to an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) [like @Mark correctly supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18235246/939860) is to use a [**string literal**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS):

```
'{projector,PAsystem,safe}'::equipment[]  -- cast optional
```

This variant is shorter and some clients have problems with the ARRAY constructor, which is a function-like element.

Plus, the **cast is optional** in this context (for cleaner code, better readability). Since the literal is type *unknown* initially (unlike the result of an ARRAY constructor!), Postgres will derive the type from the target column, and everything just works.

It's always been like that - tested for Postgres 9.3 or later:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0ae6f57306b40b8c470ae487baf05efc)*  - Postgres 14

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0ae6f57306b40b8c470ae487baf05efc)*  - Postgres 9.5

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ca988/1) - Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 19):

Additionally to @harm answer, you can skip quotations marks:

```sql
INSERT INTO lecture_room (equipment) VALUES ('{projector, safe}');
```

Answer (score 18):

Old question, but a new answer. In modern versions of Postgres (tested with 9.6) none of this is required. It works as expected:

```
INSERT INTO lecture_room (equipment) VALUES ('{"projector", "safe"}');
```

Comment: Does this handle duplicates automatically or is additional checking required? For example if `projector` is already in the `equipment` column of `lecture_room`, will we see two entries of `projector`?

Comment: No, there is no duplicate check. For inserts/updates the values are exactly the array you provide. And note that this is an array, not a set. You will have to perform any duplicate check yourself - '{safe, safe, safe}' is legal and will be stored as three values.