# Why am I getting an error in this simple INSERT query?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

Working with Postgres 14 on Win 10. Running this simple query:

```sql
mydata=# SELECT * FROM contact_test;
 cntct_id | fname | lname | email | street | unit | town | state | post_code
----------+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+------+-------+-----------
(0 rows)


mydata=# INSERT INTO contact_test (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('Robert', 'Johnson', 'rjohnsonn@gmail.com');
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Robert"
LINE 1: ...T INTO contact_test (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('Robert', ...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

I looked up the syntax here:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-insert.html

The sample essentially looks the same as my statement:

```
INSERT INTO products (product_no, name, price) VALUES
(1, 'Cheese', 9.99);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the type of the `fname` column? If you are using psql, you can check with `\d contact_test`.

Comment: Here is the output: ~~~ cntct_id  | bigint   |           | not null | generated always as identity
 fname     | "char"[] |           | not null |
 lname     | "char"[] |           | not null |
 email     | "char"   |           | not null |

Comment: I must confess that I’m not sure how to interpret `"char"[]`, but I *think* it means that the column is of type “array of single characters”. Is that what you want? If you want to handle multiple first names, something like `text[]` would seem more appropriate or, for a single first name, just `text`.

Comment: @TurePålsson is right, you should consult [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html). it says, insertion on array should use `{` - something like `{"name1", "name2"}` which does not suit the simple need to store variable-length string. we have no clue why did you make the columns this way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the all-essential table definition.

Answer (score 4):

Given the table definition you added in a comment, this statement would work:

```
INSERT INTO contact_test (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('{R}', '{J}', 'r');
```

`fname` and `lname` are *array* types, so you need to pass *array literals* (or *array constructors*). Examples:

- [PostgreSQL INSERT into an array of enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234946/postgresql-insert-into-an-array-of-enums/18237969#18237969)
- [Error "invalid input syntax for integer" for a non-integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945824/error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-for-a-non-integer/47946767#47946767)
- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

But your table definition is nonsense, of course. You don't want the internal enumeration type `"char"`, which holds a single ASCII letter. You want `varchar` or `text`. And I am not convinced you want array types, either. (`"char"[]` is an array of `"char"`.)
Fix your table definition accordingly! Like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contact_test (
  cntct_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, fname text NOT NULL
, lname text NOT NULL
, email text NOT NULL
);
```

Then your original `INSERT` statement works.

See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Comment: Interesting. I made this table using pgAdmin4, a GUI to postgresql. The column creation dialog didn't offer "varchar" or "text" as a type option. I'll recreate the table in psql as you recommended and try it out. Thanks much!

Comment: @tom_ep pgAdmin4 has those choices, though `varchar` is shown as `character varying` or `character varying []` for array.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver I wish I could post an image here, (can I? New to stackoverflow), The options I see in the Add Column dialog are: "char", "char"[], aclitem, aclitem[], bigint, bigint[], bigserial, bit. That's it!

Comment: @tom_ep, pgAdmin4 version? The list you show is sorted and I'm betting you are only looking at the top selections. I'm also betting the drop down list under Data Type has a vertical slide bar that allows you to get past the top items and into more choices. If not there is something wrong with your pgAdmin4 install.

Comment: @Adam Klaver Wow, do I feel like an idiot! In my defense, it is a slide dot almost the same color as the background.Time for new glasses! Yes, there are many more type options. Thanks much for your patience!